# Present or future tense for "then"?

Tags: word-choice, tense

I have the following sentence:

> Then by selecting the two anchors from the list of anchors and selecting the “Common Ancestor” option, the context **(is or will be ?)** created.

I don't know if I should "is" or "will be", as it shown in the sentence.

Comment: If it's generally true, use the present (every time you select this option, this happens). If it is more of a one time/one-off event, or the result is less immediate, use the future to show that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the case where this is a step in an instruction, I would use "will be", because you read the instruction and then perform it.

If it is just documentation, then either should be OK, but I would prefer "is".